# Adding Parameters to init function of inherited class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am quite new to inheritance and overriding methods and i am not quite sure how to override the `__init__` method of a class, more specifically, adding another parameter to it.

Basically i want to override the `__init__` method of the tkinter class simpledialog.Dialog.

From the documentation the **init** method of simpledialog.Dialog has the Parameters `__init__(self,parent,title=None)` and i want it to be `__init__(self,parent,labeltitle,title=None)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so for context i also changed some of the other methods of the class, i will give you the code so that people know why i want labeltitle in the **init** method. I found a solution on how to solve my problem, if anyone has an idea or sees a problem with this let me know.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog

class MyDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):

    def __init__(self,parent,labeltitle,title):
        self.labeltitle=labeltitle
        super().__init__(parent,title)


    def body(self, master):
        self.geometry("400x300")
        tkinter.Label(master, text=self.labeltitle).grid(row=0)

        self.e1 = tkinter.Entry(master)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1,pady=30)
        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()
        self.result = first
```

so now when i create an Object of MyDialog like this:
asd = MyDialog(root,"title_of_the_label","title_of_the_Dialogwindow")
i get the Dialogwindow with these titles. Now i can create multiple objects with different windowtitles and labeltitles, since the simpledialog.Dialog class only allowed to change the title of the Dialogwindow, not the labeltitle.